# What would be synonyms for "be into something"?

Tags: vocabulary

I find myself repeatedly using these two expressions;

**"I'm into Psychology"** or **"I'm interested in Psychology"**

but cannot think of other ways to deliver the same meaning.

What other expressions people in US/UK use?

Comment: How formal a term do you want?  Every decade seems to produce new slang for this concept.

Comment: @Jasper - Indeed. I mean, conceivably we could say, "Psychology [floats my boat](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/float+someone%27s+boat)," but I would never recommend such a dated idiom to a learner.

Comment: @J.R. That idiom isn't really dated, is it?

Comment: @userr2684291 - Maybe not dated per se, but in this context, I think it would sound corny and out of place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fascinated or Intrigued are two that I can think of off the top of my head.

"I'm fascinated by Psychology." or "Psychology fascinates me."

or

"I'm intrigued by Psychology." or "Psychology intrigues me."

Answer (score 5):

You can say 'I am crazy about psychology' to mean you have great interest in the subject.

> [crazy:](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/crazy)
>   2 *informal* Extremely enthusiastic.
>   ‘I'm crazy about Cindy’
>   *[in combination]* ‘a football-crazy bunch of boys’
>   ‘And you were crazy about him, too, once, remember?’
>   ‘I like the melody of the acoustic guitar here, but I'm not crazy about the fact that it's acoustic guitar or that it's put with those other instruments.’
>   ‘No wonder some kids aren't so crazy about books.’
>
> (Oxford Dictionary of English)

Comment: As an added benefit, it's somewhat punny/self-referential.

Answer (score 2):

How about something as simple as the verb **to like**?

> I **like** psychology.

After all, that's what you most often hear people say about things they're interested in. For instance, a person might say "I like math" (or maths, if you're British) to let you know that they like studying mathematics.

Another possible way to express the idea of being interested in something, I think, would be the expressions **to be enthusiastic about something** and **to be a something enthusiast**. For example:

> I'm **enthusiastic** about psychology.
>
> I'm **a psychology enthusiast**.

So, when you say that you're a math enthusiast, for example, it usually implies that you do mathematics on a, sort of, semi-professional level, but one thing is certain about you—doing mathematics is probably not your main source of income. In other words, you're not a professionally-trained mathematician.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm passionate about psychology

and

> Psychology is my passion

are also options.

To me, the latter expression seems to emphasize that psychology is your **MAIN** topic of interest, so it may or may not be appropriate based on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can say:

> I am obsessed with Psychology